# using jquery-ui with browserify

Tags: jquery-ui, browserify

My source `browserify` `coffeeify` file:

```
$ = jQuery = require 'jquery'
require 'jq-ui'
$ ->
    jqueryUiIsLoaded = jQuery.ui
    console.log "jquery-ui is loaded: #{jqueryUiIsLoaded}"
```

which I convert to `main.js` with command:

```
browserify source.coffee -t coffeeify > main.js --debug
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jquery_ui_test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "main": "browserify source.coffee -t coffeeify > main.js --debug"
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "jq-ui": "./node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jq-ui": {
      "exports": "jq-ui",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^6.0.2",
    "coffeeify": "^0.7.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5"
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='./main.js'/>
</head>
</html>
```

In browser console I see that jquery ui is not loaded:

```
jquery-ui is loaded: undefined source.coffee:5
```

What should I do to make `jquery-ui` load with `browserify`?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work without using Bower?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in using `debowerify`: 
I installed `jquery` and `jquery-ui` via `bower`.
My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "jquery_ui_test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "main": "browserify source.coffee -t coffeeify -t debowerify > main.js --debug"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "<6",
    "coffeeify": "^0.7.0",
    "debowerify": "^0.8.2"
  }
}
```

My `source.coffee` is :

```
$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery")
require "jquery-ui"
jqueryUiIsLoaded = jQuery.ui
console.log "jquery-ui is loaded: #{jqueryUiIsLoaded}"
```

And browser console output is:

`jquery-ui is loaded: [object Object]`

So `jquery-ui` is working.

Comment: So how do you load for example just the autocomplete without it loading the whole library?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to load autocomplete without the whole jquery ui, isn't it?

Comment: Normally you can pick and choose what gets included... http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: @IanWarburton nice to know. I this case `debowefy` will not help you or you can work around by replacing `./bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js` by your cutted version.